# XSpec / Saxon - EXSLT format-date

Tags: java, saxon, xspec

I'm using XSpec (with Saxon EE 9) to test some XSLT 1.0 transforms. They work fine for the most part, except for the following EXSLT extension:

```
<xsl:value-of select="exsldt:format-date(value[@name='outputFileGenerated'], 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')" />
```

I get an error saying:

> {http://exslt.org/dates-and-times}format-date(). There is no Saxon
>   extension function with   the local name format-date

I understand that this means Saxon hasn't implemented the format-date() method from EXSLT. Is there a way around this, without changing my Transform?

Answer (score 0):

The only way around it would be to implement the function yourself, either in Java or in XSLT. Note that if you write an implementation in XSLT (using xsl:function) you can use the attribute override="no" to indicate that if an external function with the same name is present, that should take precedence.